# Put forward a chart with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Below script create a chart and an array at the upper left corner.

How can we put forward the array so we can't see the Y axis through it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,4))
ax = fig.gca()

f = lambda x : np.power(1.2, x)
x0 = np.arange(*(0,100))
y0 = f(x0)

ax.plot(x0,y0)
ax.legend(['f(x)'])
ax.set_title('Exp')

index = ['index1', 'index2', 'index3', 'index4', 'index5']
values = [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5']]

table = ax.table(cellText=values, colWidths=[0.15, 0.15], rowLabels=index, loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zorder to control its position.

```
table = ax.table(cellText=values, colWidths=[0.15, 0.15], rowLabels=index, loc='upper left', zorder=10)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Do you know how to make the first row of the array start at the upper left of the picture and not just the upper left of the graph?